# How to rebuild a [FloatingActionButton] in [Scaffold] after pressing [BackButton] in [AppBar] in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, transition, rebuild

is there an elegant way to rebuild a [FloatingActionButton] in a [Scaffold] after pressing the [BackButton] of an [AppBar]?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you need from that description, but you could try making your widget implement [RouteAware](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) - that way it can know whether the route it pushed, was popped.

So for example, then you could do a

```
 @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // Do something that updates the state that ensures your button is
    // rebuilt.
  }
```